# Not chaging Text.Color in disabled Button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want change the `Text.Color` when the `Button` is disable. How can I do it?

Xaml Button:

```
<Button Text="-" TextColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="#3F3C42" Clicked="QntLabelLess" x:Name="QntLess" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void QntLabelLess(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            if (Qnt == 2)
            {
                QntLess.IsEnabled = false;
               // QntLess.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
                QntLess.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#3F3C42");              
            } 
            if (Qnt == 10)
            {
                QntPlus.IsEnabled = true;
                QntPlus.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#000000");
                QntPlus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF8A00");         
            }
            Qnt--;        
            QntLabel.Text = Qnt.ToString();
 }
```

I know that have a lot of useless code for this question but I prefer put all my method code.

Comment: This only happens when disabled?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes, looks like Disabled button have a default Text.Color and I cant change it. I tested change only the Text and the BackgroundColor and it changed, this only happens with Text.Color.

Comment: try changing the `TextColor` first then disabling the button!?

Comment: @G.hakim Didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, the button starts in a disabled state. Because of this, your click event will never get called because the button is already disabled. I'm guessing you ONLY see the button in the disabled state and never in an enabled state.

Comment: My click event to enable the button isn't click on it, my button "+" is responsable to enable it. The only thing that doesnt work in this code is the Text.Color of the button "-" when it is disabled. Maybe you got that conclusion because I didn´t show my xaml code of my "+" button and the code behind of it. But dont mind this, isn´t so important, but thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that ,you should achieve a custom renderers  for button.
Here is running GIF.

[image]

For Android.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace ButtonStyle.Droid
{

public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void 
    OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> args)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(args);
        if (Control != null) SetColors();
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, 
    PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, args);
        if (args.PropertyName == nameof(Xamarin.Forms.Button.IsEnabled)) SetColors();
    }

    private void SetColors()
    {
        Control.SetTextColor(Element.IsEnabled ? Element.TextColor.ToAndroid() : 
        Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Element.IsEnabled ? 
        Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid() : Android.Graphics.Color.Purple);
    }
 }
}
```

For IOS(I did not take my Mac today, you had better to test it for yourself)

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
 namespace ButtonStyle.iOS
 {
  public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
 {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> args)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(args);
        if (Control != null) SetColors();
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, 
     PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, args);
        if (args.PropertyName == nameof(Button.IsEnabled)) SetColors();
    }

    private void SetColors()
    {
        Control.SetTitleColor(Element.IsEnabled ? Element.TextColor.ToUIColor() : 
       UIColor.Red, Element.IsEnabled ? UIControlState.Normal : 
      UIControlState.Disabled);
        Control.BackgroundColor = Element.IsEnabled ? 
      Element.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor() : UIColor.Purple;
    }
}
```

There is code MainPage.xaml

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonStyle"
         x:Class="ButtonStyle.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <Label  x:Name="QntLabel" Text="1"/>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button Text="------------------------" TextColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="#3F3C42" Clicked="QntLabelLess" x:Name="QntLess"/>
    <Button Text="++++++++++++++++++++++++" TextColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="#3F3C42" Clicked="QntLabelPlus" x:Name="QntPlus"/>

</StackLayout>
```

There is code for MainPage.xaml.cs

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void QntLabelLess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Qnt=2;
        if (Qnt == 2)
        {
          //  QntLess.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000");
        //    QntLess.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#3F3C42");
            QntLess.IsEnabled = false;


        }
        if (Qnt == 10)
        {
            QntPlus.IsEnabled = true;
            QntPlus.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000");
            QntPlus.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF8A00");
        }
        Qnt--;
        QntLabel.Text = Qnt.ToString();
    }

    private void QntLabelPlus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.